# When I run my code python just sits there and doesnt print anything

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, average

> **Exercise:** Starting from the back of the string find all the numbers which could possibly lead to a number which is greater than or equal to 100, then stop and find the average of the number before that.

```
def avgBackwList(values):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1,len(values)+1):
        while values[-i] <= 100:
            total = total + int(values[-i])
    return (total/i)

values = [110,2,4]
print(avgBackwList(values))
```

Comment: please read [ask], format your question properly if you want "halp"...

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your while loop will never finish unless you pass in a list with a final value > 100

Comment: add something like i +=1 in while loop, so that value of i increases other wise the loop is infinite

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
        while values[-i] <= 100:
```

will cause the function to loop for as long as `values[i]` is less than or equal to 100. Since nothing in the `while` block changes `values[i]`, if the loop is entered at all it will never terminate.

There are other problems with your function which mean that it won't work correctly, but to start with, you could try changing that line to

```
        while total <= 100:
```

... which at least has a chance of terminating, because `total` is altered inside the `while` block.

Comment: thanks! so should changing the while loop to an if statement a better option?

Comment: Try it and see :-) To be honest, I think it's going to take you a few iterations to get from the code you have to a working solution ... since this is obviously an assignment, I prefer to point out the immediate problem that was blocking you, rather than provide a complete working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in your function evaluates the bool values[-1]<= 100. Since this is true, it never breaks the loop.

Comment: I think at the point where OP gets stuck in the while loop it will be evaluating `values[-1] <= 100`, not `values[-2]`.

Comment: Not true. you can test this by printing values[-i]. Maybe your confusing the index -1 as the object i. His code iters over the list starting with index -2 and then goes into a while loop. 4 <100 so it never returns.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you. All I am saying is that the first time through the loop `for i in range(1,len(values)+1)` the value of `i` will be `1`, and so `-i` will be `-1`. In addition, the value at the index of `-2` is `2`, and `4` is at index `-1`. Open a python interpreter and do `print([110,2,4][-2])` if you do not believe me. Also, you can try `for i in range(1,len(values)+1): print(i, -i)` and you will see `1`, `-1`. I have not downvoted your answer, because your logic is correct, I was just suggesting that you fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an infinite `while` loop. The condition for your while loop is:

```
while values[-i] <= 100:
```

In order for this loop to every end, eventually `values[-i] <= 100` needs to evaluate to `False`. However, `i` in your case will never have a  chance to change, because the `while` loop needs to finish for the `for` loop to continue. To make it a little more clear what is happening, observe the following:

```
In [8]: for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     j = 0
   ...:     while j < 5:
   ...:         print(j)
   ...:         j += 1

a
0
1
2
3
4
b
0
1
2
3
4
c
0
1
2
3
4
```

In other words, the for loop gets to the value `'a'`, then the while loop finishes going though 0-4, and only then does the outer for loop get to `'b'`, and so on. For your sake, I don't want to solve your homework assignment for you. I will say though, that with regards to your current code, you will need to find a way to make your `while` condition eventually `False`, without relying on a change to values produced by the outer for loop.